# MariaDB does not use index on join until a duplicate index is not defined

Tags: join, indexing, mariadb

I have noticed a weird behavior in MariaDB with joins. Although the join condition is on the indexed columns, MariaDB doesn't use it until a duplicate index for the same columns is defined.

These are my simple table definitions -

```
MariaDB [ac]> show create table employee;
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| employee | CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `sal` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [ac]> show create table employee_details;
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table            | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| employee_details | CREATE TABLE `employee_details` (
  `id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `empkey` (`id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

And the explain output when I insert a single record and attempt to perform a join -

```
MariaDB [ac]> explain select * from employee e inner join employee_details ed on e.id=ed.id and e.name=ed.name;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1    |                                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ed    | ALL  | empkey        | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1    | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

**Notice that it lists the *empkey* in the possible keys but doesn't use it**.
And then I added another key for the same set of fields, and performed a join, it uses the new index -

```
MariaDB [ac]> alter table employee_details add key empkey1(id, name);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.006 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

MariaDB [ac]> explain select * from employee e inner join employee_details ed on e.id=ed.id and e.name=ed.name;
+------+-------------+-------+------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ALL  | PRIMARY        | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              | 1    |       |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ed    | ref  | empkey,empkey1 | empkey1 | 934     | ac.e.id,ac.e.name | 1    |       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

This time both the keys are listed in the possible keys list, and **the new index is used**.

I attempted this with a large number of records and the results were the same. This is on MariaDB 10.6.8.

Comment: with large number , is the second faster or not?

Comment: It is faster. But it is weird that we had to add the duplicate index to make it faster.

Comment: write a bug report to the developers

Comment: Removed mysql tag, because mariadb is not mysql.